# Filtering contents of an HTML input element using a server-side script

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

This php script remove all `<a></a>` tags
i want placed this php script in html form when i click remove button of form they remove all `<a></a>` tags 
please any expert convert this script in form

```
<?php

$str = 'I would like <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> this link.';
$filter = preg_replace("/<a(.*)<\/a>/iUs", "", $str);

print $filter;
?>
```

i want use this form

```
<form>
<textarea name="" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Remove all <a></a>" onClick="">
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Do you want your form to send a request to the PHP script so that you can strip `<a></a>` tags and get the result?

Comment: Incredible how some SO people have no patience with non-native English speakers. Let Ahmed respond within 30 minutes before you start downvoting, voting to close and so on - it has now only been 10 minutes!!! There are now 3 suggestions that he needs to look at and then he can perhaps reformulate the question for us

Comment: @mplungjan, I guess he was a downvote victim due to the dumb regex-html meme. (That's sometimes like saying Jehova around here.)

Comment: I have re-titled this question for accuracy and findability.

Comment: I think the title should be `Filtering contents of an HTML input element using a client-side script based on a server-side script`

Comment: @mario: I'm warning you. If you say 'REGEX-HTML' once more....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
<script type="javascript">
function removeAll(theForm) {
  var str = theForm.text.value;
  if (str) theForm.text.value = str.replace(/<a(.*)<\/a>/ig,"");
}
</script>
<form>
  <textarea name="text" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Remove all anchors" onclick="removeAll(this.form)" />
</form>
```

or

```
<script type="javascript">
function validate(theForm) {
  var str = theForm.text.value;
  if (str && str.match(/<a(.*)<\/a>/ig)) {
    alert('Please do not enter any links')
    theForm.text.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  <textarea name="text" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send to server" />
</form>
```

You still need to test on the server since JS could be turned off

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to filter HTML with a regex.

Please don't.

Take a look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), a comprehensive HTML filtering mechanism in PHP.  Using it, you can ensure that the HTML your users are submitting fits a particular set of guidelines, like ensuring there are no anchor tags.